# Member not found on using jquery 1.11.0 in internet explorer 8

Tags: jquery

```
            <link href="/sites/mysitename/SiteAssets/JS/lightslider.css">
            <script src="/sites/mysitename/SiteAssets/JS/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
            <script src="/sites/mysitename/SiteAssets/JS/lightslider.js"></script>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

                function isTrustedIE(){ 
                    try{
                        var test=new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
                        return true;
                    }
                    catch(e){
                        return false;
                    }
                }


                $(document).ready(function(){
```

> > > I am using a third party carousal (lightslider js)    problem is
> > >       when i open IE 8 the images are not loading , and when i  press
> > >       ctrl + f5  ... 2 3 times it comes adding to that a script error comes "Member not found for jquery 1.11.0" i googled and came across
> > >       preventDefault() but still i am ubable to solve the issue
>
> Thanks in adavance

```
                         $("#content-slider").lightSlider({
                                item: 1,
                                loop: true,
                                auto:true,
                                slideMargin: 5,
                                mode: "slide",
                                useCSS: true,
                                cssEasing: 'ease',
                                easing: 'linear',
                                thumbItem: 0, 
                                gallery: false,
                                speed: 200, //ms'
                                auto: true,
                                loop: true,
                                slideEndAnimation: true,

                        });

                var siteUrl = window.location.protocol +"//"+ window.location.hostname +"/sites/mysitename/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";

                    //Soap for Images
                    var soapimages = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
                                <soap:Body> \
                                <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                                <listName>images</listName> \
                                <query><Query> \
                                </Query></query>\
                                <viewFields> \
                                <ViewFields> \
                                <FieldRef Name='Name'/> \
                                <FieldRef Name='FileRef'/> \
                                </ViewFields> \
                                </viewFields> \
                                <rowLimit>5</rowLimit> \
                                <queryOptions xmlns:SOAPSDK9='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'><QueryOptions/> \
                                </queryOptions> \
                                </GetListItems> \
                                </soap:Body> \
                                </soap:Envelope>";

                    //Soap call for Header Text
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: siteUrl ,
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "xml",
                        data: soapimages ,
                        complete: function(xData, status){                  
                            jQuery(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function () {
                                    var bannerURL = $(this).attr("ows_FileRef").split(";#")[1];
                                    var newli = '<li><img class="imgCarousal" src="/'+bannerURL+'"/></li>';
                                    $('#content-slider').append(newli);
                                    $('img.imgCarousal').each(function() 
                                        {
                                            var maxWidth =990; // Max width for the image
                                            var maxHeight =230;// Max height for the image
                                            var ratio = 0; // Used for aspect ratio
                                            var width = $(this).width(); // Current image width
                                            var height = $(this).height(); // Current image height
                                            // Check if the current width is larger than the max
                                                    if(width > maxWidth)
                                                        {
                                                            ratio = maxWidth / width; // get ratio for scaling image
                                                            $(this).css("width", maxWidth); // Set new width
                                                            $(this).css("height", height * ratio); // Scale height based on ratio
                                                            height = height * ratio; // Reset height to match scaled image
                                                            width = width * ratio; // Reset width to match scaled image
                                                        }
                                                    // Check if current height is larger than max
                                                    if(height > maxHeight)
                                                        {
                                                            ratio = maxHeight / height; // get ratio for scaling image
                                                            $(this).css("height", maxHeight); // Set new height
                                                            $(this).css("width", width * ratio); // Scale width based on ratio
                                                            width = width * ratio; // Reset width to match scaled image
                                                        }
                                            });
                                });
                        },
                        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
                    });


                });

            </script>
            <style>
            img.imgCarousal
                {
                    width:990px !important;
                }
           #container-carousal
                {   
                    width:1000px;
                    padding:0px!important;
                    height:300px;
                }

            ul  {
                    list-style: none outside none;
                    padding-left: 0;
                    margin-bottom:0;
                }

            </style>


                      <div id="container-carousal">
                        <ul id="content-slider" class="content-slider">

                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Comment: This question is quite hard to read -- consider separating your question from the code. Also, I believe the word you're looking for is [carousel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carousel). [Carousal](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/carousal) is also a word, but means something very different.

Comment: I will try to put in this way that i get en error msg after integrating lightslider js [a plug in] into a site
jquery version 1.11.0
Carousal [link] (http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/index.html)